# How to straighten an Aloe vera plant?

Tags: plant-health, aloe

I have a huge Aloe. I've had it for about 3 years and it was huge before I got it. It just blossomed for the first time. Actually I should say it has a first time bud. All I do is water it and leave on an indoor sunny porch.

I got busy with work  and she mass produced. Here is my problem, when I transferred her to a larger pot she was perfectly centered, she looks very healthy but now is lying over the side of the pot. I want her more centered. Any ideas?

Comment: I think a photo might be very useful, can you add one please?

Comment: Stake it either side, or form a square around with four stakes, and tie with soft material (easiest is an old pair of pantyhose), being careful not to make it too tight.

Answer (score 1):

omg,,, i have one too..!i repotted mine also, same thing.i think because the leaves are so fleshy the weight pulls them over. i would just go with it,or,thin it out and start over. if nothing else you have a conversation piece.. Graham,it will just continue to grow as long as it has room. I suggest either thinning it out and get some new ones growing from the off shoots, re-pot it again or just get rid of it. Maybe start some new ones and sell them.?!Remember they are medicinal. Mine is a monster. I just may get rid of it. I already have plenty of plants. Sorry if my 1st answer wasn't complete.Good Luck.

Comment: @JimYoung isn't she answering suggesting to thin it?

Comment: @Graham Chiu, I suppose; if the "omg,,, i have one too..!i repotted mine also, same thing. opening remark was deleted it might appear to be more like an answer. Still it impresses me as being very close to the example of a poor answer. Albeit that it isn't for me to judge, but how does thinning possibly correct the problem of the plant now hanging over the side of the pot?. Further, what does 'start over' mean? Would it mean repot it, but this time sit it deeper in the pot? I presume it doesn't mean do again what you did before that didn't work, but what is it?

Comment: it would be good if she would add that to her answer

Comment: I read "start over" as grab an offset and center it in a different pot. I also read "mass produced" to mean the plant put out a lot of offsets, not just got larger. Aloes can be difficult plants to train. Depending on the species it will offset relentlessly. In a battle of wills with an aloe, you are likely to lose.