# Is something wrong with my Aloe Vera?

Tags: growth, repotting, aloe, dryness

I have an Aloe Vera, although I am thinking its not very healthy as its quite limp and thin. I am thinking I need to repot into something larger/deeper. I water it once or twice every week or 2 and try to put it in the sun when I can. 
There is a new sprout growing in the middle so I dont think it is dying
any advice will help :)

Thanks

[image: Aloe Vera]

Comment: Similar, it might help: https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/24033/how-to-straighten-an-aloe-vera-plant

Comment: The last thing it needs is a bigger pot, it looks like the pot's too big for it already, and it also appears to be planted well below the top of the pot, is there a reason for that? Do you empty out that tray or plastic container when it catches water after you've watered,  or  do you leave it in there?

Answer (score 5):

From what I see here, your Aloe gets too much water for the sun it get. Aloe Vera leaves in very hot, sunny places (often sandy). [e.g. already discussed here](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/2154/how-do-you-save-an-aloe-plant-whose-stem-is-weak-and-appears-to-be-rotting?rq=1).

It goes for the sun ([phototropism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phototropism)) because it doesn't have enough. That explains the long thing leaves we see on your plant.

Result of frequent watering, lots of water is pumped into the leaves, making them heavy, too heavy, and finally breaking.

**Solution**:

- Try to find a better sunnier place, or water more scarcely.
- You can harvest the bottom leaves while there green.

Comment: Agree this looks over watered. Also try repotting in a smaller/shallower container until it grows a bit more, it looks a bit bizarre as it is, and it would probably help its form without the sides of the pot surrounding it.

Comment: We keep our aloes fairly well watered, in the shade, and in big pots. I had one that acted like this and it was in shallow soil. When I replanted it in deeper soil, in a bigger pot, it started growing better. I woudn't keep the dish underneath full of water though.